# From Postgress regexp replace match in PHP language

Tags: php, regex, postgresql, regexp-replace

i need some help.

I have PostgreSQL regexp_replace pattern, like:

```
 regexp_replace(lower(institution_title),'[[:cntrl:]]|[[[:digit:]]|[[:punct:]]|[[:blank:]]|[[:space:]|„|“|“|”"]','','g')
```

and i need this one alternative in PHP language

Because one half is from postgress db, and i have to compare strings from php aswell.

Comment: The same regex can be used in PHP, here is an enhanced version of it: `preg_replace('/[[:cntrl:][:digit:][:punct:][:blank:][:space:]„““”"]+/u', '', strtolower(institution_title))`

Comment: Please check the spelling of your title: https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Identity_Guidelines

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use the same POSIX character classes with PHP PCRE regex:

```
preg_replace('/[[:cntrl:][:digit:][:punct:][:blank:][:space:]„““”"]+/', '', strtolower($institution_title))
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/xR5pW1/1)

Besides, there are [Unicode category classes](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.unicode.php) in PCRE. Thus, you may also try

```
preg_replace('/[\p{Cc}\d\p{P}\s„““”"]+/u', '', mb_strtolower($institution_title, 'UTF-8'))
```

Where `\p{Cc}` stands for Control characters, `\d` for digits, `\p{P}` for punctuation, and `\s` for whitespace.

I am adding `/u` modifier to handle Unicode strings, too.

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/sG3rR7/1)

Comment: I cannot match strings, 
here is my output of postgres sql:

SQL:
`select regexp_replace(lower(title),'[[:cntrl:]]|[[[:digit:]]|[[:punct:]]|[[:blank:]]|[[:space:]|„|“|“|”"]','','g')
from cls_institutions`

SQL:
`"oxforduniversity"
"šiauliųuniversitetas"
"harwarduniversity"
"žemaitijoskolegija"`

PHP: `$institutions[] = "'".preg_replace('/[[:cntrl:][:digit:][:punct:][:blank:][:space:]„““”"]+/', '', strtolower($data[0]))."'";`

PHP:
`"oxforduniversity",
"Šiauliųuniversitetas",
"harwarduniversity",
"Žemaitijoskolegija",`
First letter is not lowered case, somehow... I am missing something?

Comment: As I wrote in my answer, with  Unicode, you need to use `/u` regex modifier and `mb_strtolower()` to turn Unicode letters to lower case.

Answer (score 0):

hanks guys, but i bumped to another problem, i cannot match strings, if there is specifik symbols,

here is my output of postgres sql:

SQL:

```
select regexp_replace(lower(title),'[[:cntrl:]]|[[[:digit:]]|[[:punct:]]|[[:blank:]]|[[:space:]|„|“|“|”"]','','g')
from cls_institutions
```

Output:

```
"oxforduniversity"
"šiauliųuniversitetas"
"harwarduniversity"
"internationalbusinessschool"
"vilniuscollege"
"žemaitijoskolegija"
"worldhealthorganization"
```

But in PHP is output is a little bit different: I got my array with institutions:

```
$institutions[] = "'".preg_replace('/[[:cntrl:][:digit:][:punct:][:blank:][:space:]„““”"]+/', '', strtolower($data[0]))."'";
```

And PHP outputs like this:

```
"oxforduniversity",
"Šiauliųuniversitetas",
"harwarduniversity",
"internationalbusinessschool",
"vilniuscollege",
"Žemaitijoskolegija",
"worldhealthorganization"
```

First letter is not lowered case, somehow... I am missing something?